Integrated GraphQL cache is not working in Sitecore XP
We have an on-prem Sitecore XP solution with Content Management (CM) and Content Delivery (CD) servers, integrated with a rendering host. Our implementation is headless using Next.js, and for some components, we are using integrated GraphQL to retrieve data. We are using Sitecore XP version 10.3.
We have applied output caching on these components, but every time we request a page containing these components, they always fetch fresh data from Sitecore instead of serving cached data. According to several articles, headless output caching should work similarly to MVC output caching—the main difference being that MVC caches the complete HTML while JSON rendering caches the JSON data. However, it seems that the caching is not functioning as expected for GraphQL components.
Has anyone else encountered this issue? Are there specific configurations or steps required to ensure that GraphQL data is correctly cached in a headless Sitecore setup?
Any insights, suggestions, or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Can confirm that I am running into this issue on Sitecore 10.2.1. SXA. The Site definition item has the Cache HTML flag set to true which is the standard value. I also experimented with enabling caching on a specific JSON rendering definition item and also the rendering when added to a specific page. Caching does not appear to work. My rendering this rendering contents resolver: Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.GraphQL.LayoutService.GraphQLAwareRenderingContentsResolver, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.GraphQL. Time to open a support ticket.

This will work if you have done the following:

On your site definition item, enable Cache HTML. Ensure that Html cache size (in MB) has a value. Publish the item.
Restart your CM and CD instances. HTML cache limitation is set during the initialization of Sitecore.
On your rendering definition (or page presentation details), set Cacheable to true, as well as any other options you need (Clear on index update, Vary by Data, etc.). Publish the item.

